# Does `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<TUser>` use ASP.NET Core Data Protection under the covers?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, password-hash, dpapi

**Background:**
I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 application that is running in an AWS FARGATE container (on Linux).

**What I need to do:**
I need to hash passwords using a built-in .NET Core solution. I'd prefer to use a solution where I don't have to manage key rotation; but will do so if there's no other option.

I'd like to use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<TUser>` to hash the passwords.  However, I have no idea if this uses some sort of key rotation mechanism (e.g. DPAPI) to generate the hashes.  According to [ASP.NET Core Data Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1), the ***default*** implementation handles key generation and rotation - i.e. keys are stored in the ***LOCAL*** CryptoRing and rotated by default every 90 days.  Therefore:

1. keys are not transferable
2. keys to decrypt are only good for 90 days

If I need to handle key rotation, I *think* (not sure) that the cloud-based solution is to generate a crypto key and add to Azure.  But, I need to know if I even need to do this if I'm only using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.PasswordHasher<TUser>` to hash the passwords and not using any ASP.NET Core Data Protection.  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
According to Barry Dorans (@blowdart), it does not use ASP.NET Data Protection:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21331#issuecomment-621345491

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. I know this by looking at the code, available at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs.

Comment: I'd looked at the code as well and saw it used `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator`. However, I didn't know if that was part of the Data Protection API (like `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is).

Comment: No, it’s not, this is a .NET BCL class

Comment: Just so I know, how are you able to tell the difference between whether or not a class is part of the Data Protection API or just a BCL class?  They are both in the same namespace and `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` derives from `RandomNumberGenerator` - unless I'm incorrect in saying that `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` is part of Data Protection)

Comment: Read about the Data Protection API, to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Yes, I did actually RTFM, and if you look closely you will see that `PasswordHasher` (and key derivation) are actually mentioned under the Data Protection API; which would seem to imply that they are part of it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: PasswordHasher comes with Identity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212806/discussion-between-dave-black-and-ricardo-peres).